# Ubuntu script to accept a piped command

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am writing an Ubuntu bash script that will be used in a generic form. I want to find out whether it is possible to pass a multiple commands in a piped fashion. This is what I am trying to achive:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $1 | $2 | while read line
do
    # do something
done
```

The script is to be run like this:

```
./myscript.sh data.txt "grep status | grep Approved"
```

Is this possible to be achived. I had a go, but only got far as:

```
./myscript.sh data.txt "grep status"
```

This worked.

Is this is possible? I can reuse this script to pass in different commands to do different things but each having common code i.e. myscript.sh.

When the the do something is replaced by:

```
echo $2
```

This does display what was typed in to the second argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `|` must be literally present in the command line to be interpreted as the control operator. As a result of a variable expansion, it's interpreted as the string `|`, i.e. as if you entered `'|'` on the command line.

You can use `eval` to let the shell interpret the variable as a new pipeline or command list. It opens another can of worms, though - you might need to introduce another level of quoting and you need to be careful not to run into security issues.

```
pipeline='grep a | grep b'
echo a b c | eval "$pipeline"
```